Using NumberForm in TableForm
new to Mathematica, but managed to use NumberForm and TableForm, but not at the same time. When I add NumberForm the data is no longer presented in a table.
Any suggestions what I should do instead?
TableForm[N[NumberForm[PolyhedronData["RhombicHexecontahedron", "VertexCoordinates"], {8,6}]]]


  NumberForm[
     TableForm[
      N @ PolyhedronData["RhombicHexecontahedron", "VertexCoordinates"],
      TableAlignments -> Right],
     {8, 6}]



Thank you very much. Follow-up question, since the only reason I'm using NumberForm is to add decimals (0. won't work when exporting to excel). I couldn't find out how to get '0' instead of '0.'

Does this help?: ReplaceAll[ N@PolyhedronData["RhombicHexecontahedron", "VertexCoordinates"], 0.  :>  0]

It does, just need to check the ReplaceAll command, it's not very intuitive to write :> looks more like a smiley.
Oh, just found out that it works just as good with ->
makes more sense to me.

Yes, but it displays nicely inside Mathematica (more like an arrow) :)

Hmm, actually ReplaceAll does not work because Mathematica will add a period after an integer. Must be some way to change that from 1. to 1.0 or 1

Ah, the easy way seems to be to export to excel, that works.
